# Big Query: How to extract each tables creation time for a data set?

Tags: google-bigquery

For one of my datasets, I am having a new table created at different a time every day.

Is there a way to extract / query these creation times for all tables?

Answer (score 6):

This is available as the creationTime field in the [tables.get](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get) API call.

Purely as an undocumented implementation detail of table wildcards, if you want to quickly fetch this via query you can query the __TABLES__ metatable that exists in a dataset:

```
SELECT table_id, creation_time FROM <dataset>.__TABLES__
```

Comment: Many Thanks, it worked. The metatable provides all the information required for each table.